# How can I highlight a row in the query output in the BigQuery Web UI?

Tags: user-interface, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

MySQL (and most thick database clients) allows highlighting a row in a query's output (see below). Is this possible in the BigQuery Web UI?

[image: here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the row to highlight it as if you want to copy the whole row, other than that, I don't think there is any other way to do so.

[image]